# Sine using square root

Tags: code-golf, math

Given input \$x \in \left\{0,3,6,...,90\right\}\$, output \$\sin\left(x°\right)\$ using integer and \$+ - \times \div ( ) \sqrt{\cdot}\$(square root), e.g. \$\sin(45°)=\sqrt{1\div 2}\$.

Flexible output format. You needn't do any simplification to output, aka. it's fine to output \$\sin(0°)=\sqrt{42}-\sqrt{6\sqrt{-9+58}}\$. Complex intermediate value is fine but please mention.

Shortest code wins.

Comment: What exactly is the output format? Especially for square root, how would that be represented, as I understand we're supposed to output a string of some sort.

Comment: May we use square roots to produce complex numbers in intermediate steps?

Comment: May we use - as both subtraction and as negation?  Your example shows it as subtraction. (Ideally we shouldn't have to guess the pattern from examples).

Answer (score 15):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 89 bytes

```python
c='s-1*'
y='/s+2/s++7s5s*6+5s522'
f=lambda d:d and'+*'+y+(x:=f(d-3))+'*'+c+x*2+c+y*2or'0'
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3I5Nt1Yt1DbXUuSpt1fWLtY2AWNu82LRYy0zbtNjUyEidK802JzE3KSVRIcUqRSExL0VdW0tdu1Jbo8LKNk0jRddYU1NbHSiSrF2hZQQkK7WM8ovUDdQhFqwuKMrMK9FI0wAqg4jArAYA)

It times out when trying to run it in ATO when trying to run it for large degrees, but it should work in theory. It outputs in prefix notation, where `s` is the unary square root operator; all other operators are binary. Furthermore, in this notation, there are only single digits (e.g. `20` represents a `2` then a `0`).

It works by repeatedly applying the formula
$$ \sin(a+3^{\circ}) = \sin(a) \cos(3^{\circ}) + \cos(a) \sin(3^{\circ}) \\ 
= \sin(a) \cos(3^{\circ}) + \sqrt{1-\sin(a)\sin(a)} \sqrt{1-\cos(3^{\circ})\cos(3^{\circ})}$$

where \$\cos(3^\circ) = \sin(87^\circ)\$ equals
$$\frac12 \sqrt{2+\frac12 \sqrt{7+\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{6(5+\sqrt{5})}}}$$

(according to Wolfram-Alpha).

Comment: You could golf your notation slightly by only allowing single digits, which would save thee bytes

Comment: @emanresuA Is that definitely valid?

Comment: It's a perfectly valid and unambiguous representation, and I don't think it's particularly overoptimised for this challenge (which would probably fall under a loophole)

Comment: What's the `^` in output?

Comment: @l4m2 It's the exponentiation symbol; I just realized that you don't explicitly include it in the list of allowed operators, but since the only form of exponentiation used in this equation is squaring I can easily change the code to remove the operator.

Comment: Well, it turns out doing that allowed me to shave off 11 bytes as well, so thanks :P

Comment: `y+y or'0'` => `y*2or'0'`

Answer (score 13):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 75 bytes

```python
lambda x:f"(1-1{(s:=x//3*'*(1+S(5)+S(S(20)-10))/(S(12)+S(-4))')})/S(-4{s})"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc5BboMwEAXQNT7FKJvMpBBwnEYNKqdg282kNQ4SBmKjyiXK2alRq6qbP2/@6o9f03Xo1cvolsYNFt4tT1do7Ti4CfwtBnuohanelo7t5YMhlM0GZSbv6Msq5LnabXcon2p8phg1HgrKZEGUR8vD2mVHoi09KF959w/aLM3gIEDbg@PeaCzSs0oVlSLxUIHBQCKZo/Qnd@jjw97rdcvF47xvLRuCV5A6O4tkdG0/YUhh3jvNHQnx09DvNRjH/Fn984lo@QY)

This produces an expression with complex numbers as intermediates that can be evaluated in Python with `S=cmath.sqrt`. For instance, `x=3` gives:

```python
(1*S(1+S(5)+S(2*S(5)-10))/S(S(12)+S(-4))-1/(1*S(1+S(5)+S(2*S(5)-10))/S(S(12)+S(-4))))/S(-4)
```

The main idea is to work with complex numbers, in particular roots of unity. Since \$e^{i \theta}\ = \cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta)\$ where \$i = \sqrt{-1}\$, we can work with multiples of \$\theta\$ as

$$\ \cos(k\theta) + i\sin(k\theta)= e^{i k\theta}\ = \left(e^{i \theta}\right)^k = \left( \cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta)\right)^k$$

From there, we can extract just the sine with:

$$\sin(k \theta) = \frac{\left(e^{i \theta}\right)^k-1/\left(e^{i \theta}\right)^k}{2i}$$

We can take the \$k\$ power by multiplying \$k\$ times, that is concatenating \$k\$ copies of `*stuff` in the expression, since the challenge doesn't allow exponents in the formula.

So we express \$e^{i \theta}\$ for \$\theta = 3^{\circ}\$ (three degrees), and take its \$k\$-th power by multiplying it \$k\$ times, using string repetition.

It remains to express \$e^{i \theta}\$ for \$\theta = 3^{\circ}\$. We could directly write out its sine and cosine, but it's a bit shorter to express it in terms of 36 and 30 degrees:

$$e^{i (3^\circ)} = \sqrt{e^{i (6^\circ)}} = \sqrt{e^{i (36^\circ)}e^{i (-30^\circ)}} = \sqrt{(\cos(36^\circ)+i \sin (36^\circ))(\cos(30^\circ)-i \sin (30^\circ))}$$

These angles have [relatively nice sines and cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_trigonometric_values#Common_angles). A bit of tweaking and combining terms gives this in the code's notation as:

```python
S((1+S(5)+S(2*S(5)-10))/(S(12)+S(-4)))
```

If we call `S(c)` the value above, the value we want to output is:

```python
(S(c) - 1/S(c))/S(-4)
```

using that \$\sqrt{-4} = 2i\$. Finally, an improvement from @loopwalt that saved 6 bytes is to simplify this to

```python
(1-c)/S(-4c)
```

Comment: Bit of a different answer, but you can [save quite a few bytes](https://tinyurl.com/4xkb62ft) by using a prefix notation similar to [97.100.67.109's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/266447/100664)

Comment: Can't you  write `S(20)` for `2*S(5)`?

Comment: -6 I believe `lambda x:f"(1-1{(s:=x//3*'*(1+S(5)+S(S(20)-10))/(S(12)+S(-4))')})/S(-4{s})"`

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 39 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 4.875 bytes

```
∆R∆sS
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyI9IiwiIiwi4oiGUuKIhnNTIiwiIiwiNDUiXQ==)

Bitstring:

```
000100111011111001011001001010111111101
```

Outputs square root as `sqrt(...)`, and division as `/`. Uses sympy to calculate the exact sine value, and then casts to string.

### Explained

```
∆R∆sS­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
∆R     # ‎⁡Convert the input to radians
  ∆s   # ‎⁢find sine of that
    S  # ‎⁣cast to string, which stops conversion to float. Instead, it uses the exact representation, which is expressed in terms of integers.
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Comment: I always feel a little bit silly when I write a solution in the triple-digit byte counts, then see a solution in a golfing language in under a dozen bytes :P

Comment: @97.100.97.109 I feel, if anything, the opposite.  Meaning I'll sometimes feel the builtin is just a cheat.  Not that I am against golfing languages by a longshot.  They certainly have their own beauty and finding the exact right tool or builtin for the job is undoubtedly a skill, can require broad knowledge of many languages in some cases, and is its own sort of satisfaction.   But I also often feel the more work you are doing as a programmer, from a pure problem-solving perspective, the more impressive.  TLDR: don't feel silly, it's apples and oranges.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) + SymPy, <s>41</s> 39 bytes

```python
lambda n:sin(rad(n))
from sympy import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcsxDoAgDAXQ3VN0BMNgwiSJN3HBKEpiP01h4fQY3/6kt6fAj7Tt4418nJEQaobReBpYOyUtTLWzdMosRds8UlECZZBG3JdZ3Oqdt0E0oxm49L/xAQ) Link outputs all results from `0°` to `90°`. Edit: Saved 2 bytes thanks to @loopywalt.

Comment: You can use `sympy.rad` to save two bytes.

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>132</s> 110 bytes

```ruby
f=->x{(x%60-24).abs==6?%w{(s5-1)/4 1/2 (s(30+s180)+s5-1)/8 1}[x/30]:"s(1/2+#{q=x<=>45}*(#{f[q*(x*2-90)]})/2)"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcrdCsIgGADQV5GNwafL@beNFbkeRLxokODFoGWR4Xx2C7o9nMdr@ZTiNJ1jgtiMnMoed9claD1emneCMFCBWY8EkwgCKN4GMXHc/n1CIpvIFLenKsDvtHXadDzruR8ygTo5sxGIRNIjxzZjJnGVixLd06@3kHa/35HxRKuDM97aXL4)

While existing answers are very clever (and shorter than this!), the output expressions are rather long. This recursive function uses the half-angle formulas to produce expressions that fit on a single line in all cases.

Half angle formulas (rules for determining correct sign in all quadrants are unnecessary and omitted):

`cos(a/2)=sqrt(1/2+(cos a)/2)` or `cos x=sqrt(1/2+(cos x*2)/2)`

`sin(a/2)=sqrt(1/2-(cos a)/2)` or `sin x=sqrt(1/2-(cos x*2)/2)`

Below is a development version of the code, showing how the half angle formula is used to recursively derive expressions for all inputs. There are four infinite cycles as follows:
`30>30`, `90>90`, `18>54>18`, `78>66>42>6>78`. These are broken with explicit values for 30,90,18 and 78 (note even the fairly complex base expression for 78 is much simpler than the base expression for 3 used in other answers.)

**Development code with table showing how each value is derived by recursion**

```ruby
f=->x{m=x%60
m==30?"1/2"[0,90/x]:m==18?"(sqrt5-1)/4/-2+(sqrt(30+sqrt180)/8"[0,x/13*11]:"sqrt(1/2+#{s=x<=>45}sin(#{s*(x*2-90)})/2)"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYzRCoIwGIXve4pYBNt07f83DZVmDyK7CRJ2YZQzWOiefalXh@98nDN@H7@UeiPaMA8mnK9wGIzRcCcoFekgr0EG26wdVndC/WecSoFMFlKobEeqIdsSK2Cy2iZBouaItiG7X4@y0@xNuJm2KKN3L7oip4ErUQOLTCpGYtJ4mdzw9PPilvexc9zovO@ctTH9AQ)

Answer (score 3):

## [Mathematica/Wolfram](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica), 27 bytes

```mathematica
f=FunctionExpand@Sin[#*°]&
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z/N1q00L7kkMz/PtaIgMS/FITgzL1pZ69CGWLX/AUWZeSXRIYlJOanRadGZCloKxrE6CtWZOgoGOgrGBrWxsf8B) (thx to @noodle man)

This is a function solution - `#` introduces a placeholder for argument and `&` says whatever comes before is a pure function. `°` is builtin for number of radians in a degree, `@` is function application without brackets. Beyond that just relying on the underlying symbolic computation engine.

The full list of answers can be generated via:

```mathematica
Table[f[i * 3], {i, 0, 30}]
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice first submission! Mathematica is actually on TIO: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z/N1q00L7kkMz/PtaIgMS/FITgzL1pZ69CGWLX/AUWZeSXRIYlJOanRadGZCloKxrE6CtWZOgoGOgrGBrWxsf8B "Wolfram Language (Mathematica) – Try It Online")

Comment: @noodleman thanks! I was kind of assuming Wolfram would never license it, so I didn't bother to actually check - apparently my assumptions were incorrect.